# What's the point of scaling business logic?

Tags: database, architecture, microservices, scalability, distributed-computing

I'm digging into microservices and trying to understand why do I have to scale code, not just the database, which is the actual bottleneck. Well, okay, in the world of high loads I can see the point. But for the rest, shouldn't we just learn how to orchestrate multiple DBs and multiple schemas?

---

UPD: I guess my question wasn't clear enough so I got some cool replays that don't clarify the subject. First of all, I understand why the high-load architecture requires scaling the business logic. Here I'm asking about mid-level projects: how to make them response as fast as possible. The microservices might be the answer, but no one suggests that scaling code is just one option and my project won't have millions of active users daily then I just can apply this approach for the DB layer only - divide it into smallest logical schemas possible and write the BL accordingly. Isn't it be much easier to develop and maintain since there's no need for sagas, MQ and all that?

Comment: `orchestrate multiple DBs`? no, no, no - one of the basic principles of systems integration is you should avoid integration using a shared database.

Comment: @AdamSiemion could you share a link where I can read more about that principle?

Comment: "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture", "Enterprise Integration Patterns: Designing, Build-ing, and Deploying Messaging Solutions" e.g. or [my M.Sc.](https://www.scribd.com/doc/2210272/Design-patterns-in-application-integration)

Answer (score 1):

For complex systems you actually want to be able to scale in multiple dimensions, all of which are influenced by your architectural choices. Before I answer your question, here some thoughts on the most important ones:

1. Scaling your application horizontally, e.g. for higher load / more users. I think this is what you were referring to with your question. Assuming we talk about a really large application with millions of users, where this problem becomes most prevalent, The bottlenecks are many and the persistence is just one of them. The theory of distributed systems, microservices, stateless application layers and a lot of recent technologies address this problem. For databases this is the rise of clustered databases, for the business logic this is stateless, containerized service deployment and for the infrastructure this is the rise of cloud and virtualized hardware clusters. 
   Regarding your question about databases, I'd recommend to look into the tradeoffs for scalable no-sql databases as well as cockroachdb for a clusterable, transactional and relational choice. Those choices would get you around old-school single server database constraints, which seem to be implied by the proposal to orchestrate multiple DBs.
2. Scale the organization / development size to be able to develop faster and add more features in a shorter amount of time. This is typically required as well for a successful application with millions of active users. So you will have to organize development teams with hundreds or thousands of developers. Here the bottleneck is the amount of required coordination effort. And because in many traditional large organizations the middle management is incentivized to aquire as large of a team as possible, it has happened many times that large, ineffective development teams are formed that spend most of their time aligning their work in order to produce the infamously expensive monolith style application. This problem is summarized in [Conway's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law). So the way to fight back against this for (typically younger) companies is to move towards very flat hierarchies and towards small, independent teams. The independence is a key factor here. The teams are allowed to develop their own vision (product management), perform their own development and also release their own product (a module, service, application, etc).

Then to finally come to your original question:

> why do I have to scale code

With point 1 we understand that, dependent on the number of concurrent active users and the required calculation intensity of the domain's problem, we may have to scale the business layer of the application to tens or hundreds of distributed machines to accommodate the number of concurrent network connections and achieve the workload (think of what Netflix has to do for running their service for example).

And with point 2 we understand that we cannot share databases between teams/services as this would interfere with the goal to have independent development cycles for those and eat up valuable productivity through coordination efforts.

Additional reasons to horizontally scale a business logic layer is to enable disruption free service (e.g. when a node fails there will be another one to take the requests) and to allow handling complexity by automation of tasks ([devops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) approach).

For more aspects on this I recommend reading [Martin Fowlers articles](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 10 principles of microservices. You can start improving from Database first based on your comfort level and if you have enough load you would start seeing issues on client side and start optimizing the services.

You could optimize services in many way including load balancing, caching, response  format, REST/gRPC, compression etc.